# Why am I getting error "requires a generator function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, koa

I installed the module "koa-cache-control" via npm.
I added the following lines to my index.js.

```
const cacheControl = require('koa-cache-control');
```

Then...

```
app.use(cacheControl({
   noCache: true
}));
```

Here is the error I get when starting node.
Any clues?

```
AssertionError: app.use() requires a generator function
at Application.app.use 

(/home/www/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:106:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/www/index.js:17:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using an old version of Koa. The 1.x versions used a generator-based type of middleware, which was changed to Promises in version 2.

You'll either have to update Koa or use the old version `1.0.0` of `koa-cache-control`.

Comment: I think *Are you using* part can be removed from the answer. Such things should preferably be sorted out before giving an answer. I guess you spotted the problem correctly, koa@1 is the problem here.

Comment: Hello, this is resolved by one of our devs... I do not how they did it.

Comment: Is there a way for me to delete this whole question?

Comment: Yes, there should be a `delete` button below the question's tags, next to `share`, `edit` and `flag`.